# Add or subtract to integer db field using sqlform in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I have set up the db table with the following fields:

```
db.define_table('balance', 
                Field('income', 'integer'),
                Field('income_description', "text"),
                Field('expenses', 'integer'),
                Field('expenses_discription', "text"),
                Field('loan', 'integer'),
                Field('loan_discription'))
```

then the basic function with the form:

```
def index():
    form = SQLFORM(db.balance).process()
    if form.accepted:
        redirect(URL('data_display'))
        session.flash = 'Records Successfully Updated!'
    return locals()
```

How can I add new amount to the income, the expenses or the loan each time I input and submit the form with a new integer?

I want to achieve something like this that would look like this in simple Python:

savings = (income - expenses) - loan

So each time I input a new amount for the income or the expenses or the loan, I would add that amount and update the record in the database.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is a [Computed Field](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Computed-fields):

```
>>> db.define_table('item',
        Field('unit_price','double'),
        Field('quantity','integer'),
        Field('total_price',
            compute=lambda r: r['unit_price']*r['quantity']))
>>> r = db.item.insert(unit_price=1.99, quantity=5)
>>> print r.total_price
9.95
```

In your case it would be something like this:

```
db.define_table('balance', 
    Field('income', 'integer'),
    Field('income_description', "text"),
    Field('expenses', 'integer'),
    Field('expenses_discription', "text"),
    Field('loan', 'integer'),
    Field('loan_discription')
    Field('savings', compute=lambda r: (r['income'] - r['expenses']) -r['loan'])
)
```